# Nested list elements match with new list, if list contain the same add - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have nested list like below

```
mylist=[['2','3','100', '7'],[ '9', '13'],[ '21', '23', '25'],[],['9','24','45']]
```

i should compare with the new list if elements are present then print.

```
comp_list = ['2','3','100','9','13','25','45']
```

required output :

```
new_list=[['2','3','100'],['9','13'],['25'],[],['9','45']
```

i have something like below

```
for ele in mylist:
    if ele in comp_list:
        print(ele)
```

with this code the ele is not printed. can any one please help me to solve this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try nested list comprehension as follow

```
mylist=[['2','3','100', '7'],[ '9', '13'],[ '21', '23', '25'],[],['9','24','45']]
comp_list = ['2','3','100','9','13','25','45']
new_list = [[y for y in i if y in comp_list] for i in mylist]
print(new_list)
```

If the `comp_list` is a large list it might be better to convert it to set before the comprehension because checking if a value is in a set is faster then in a list.

```
comp_set = set(comp_list)
new_list = [[y for y in i if y in comp_set] for i in mylist]
```

Output

```
[['2', '3', '100'], ['9', '13'], ['25'], [], ['9', '45']]
```

Comment: If `comp_list` is longer, might be worth making it a `set` first for O(1) lookup.

Comment: That is a valid point I'm updating the code according to that. Tnx for that.

Comment: @LeoArad I am not sure the nested List comprehension is  the solution that Darshan needs at his current python level. Maybe a classic nested for loop can work better for him at this point in time.

Comment: @balderman That may be the point, this answer is according to my approach to this problem maybe he will learn about the list comprehension from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Below (classic nested for loop)

```
mylist = [['2','3','100', '7'],[ '9', '13'],[ '21', '23', '25'],[],['9','24','45']]
comp_list = ['2','3','100','9','13','25','45']
result = []

for entry in mylist:
    tmp = []
    for x in entry:
        if x in comp_list:
            tmp.append(x)
    result.append(tmp)
print(result)
```

output

```
[['2', '3', '100'], ['9', '13'], ['25'], [], ['9', '45']]
```